# Web2py - Custom Registration & Login Form in One

Tags: web2py

I'd like to allow users to register and login from one form.

The form would require only an email address and a password. If a user enters an email address that does not exist, I'd like to register the user with the email address and password combination provided. Otherwise, the form would function like a standard login form.

model (disabling first_name, last_name, and password verification):

```
auth.settings.register_verify_password = False
db.auth_user.first_name.writable = False
db.auth_user.last_name.writable = False
```

controller (not exactly sure what to do here):

```
def index():
    //maybe submit vars to login() first, then if user does not exist submit vars to register()????

    return dict(form=auth.login(),form1=auth.register())
```

view.html (custom form):

```
           <form method="POST">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="auth_user_email" name="email">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="auth_user_password" name="password">
                          </div>
                          <button type="submit">Go</button>
            {{=form.custom.end}}
```

What's the best way to accomplish this task in Web2py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In your controller, **auth.login_bare** is the trick:

```
email, password = request.post_vars['email'], request.post_vars['password']
if not auth.login_bare(email, password):
     db.auth_user.insert(
          first_name=None,
          last_name=None,
          email=email,
          password=db.auth_user.password.requires[0](password)[0]
     )
     auth.login_bare(email, password)
#redirect
```

Note, auth.login_bare will automatically login the user if username and password exist. If the combination doesn't exist, then we manually insert a user into the db.

*Fyi, you should probably validate the email before inserting a user to the db, but for simplicity I left that out.*

> In your view, a simple or custom form will do:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"
  action="{{=URL()}}" method="post"> <!--{{#or use =form.custom.begin}}-->
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
     </div>
     <button type="submit">
           Submit
     </button>
</form> <!--{{#or use =form.custom.end}}-->
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this in a couple of hours and let you know how it goes. Appreciate the input.

Comment: Great! Btw, I made some minor changes. Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: FYI - "dbauth.auth_user" should be "db.auth_user". What exactly is this doing, btw: db.auth_user.password.requires[0](password)[0]? Just want to understand why this works.

Comment: @datasci Thanks it's fixed. That snippet, it's the default validation method of the password field for auth_user. It basically returns a PBKDF2 key derivation of the password, rather than the plain-text password itself... PBKDF2 derivation is kind of like a MD5 hash checksum, but much more secure. I'm sure you know the reason for doing this. 

For those who don't know, it is not safe to store the password in plain-text, but rather it's better to store a "signature" of the password, and generate/compare the signature each time the user logs in. That web2py validator does all this automatically.